# Xamarin.Forms UINavigationBar in PageRenderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, renderer

I have a page renderer for camera and I want to put bottom menu on this renderer page in native not Xamarin.Forms page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to place NavigationBar at bottom of the screen in PageRenderer?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the `Frame` of `View` and `NavigationBar` in PageRenderer.

#### Create Custom Renderer for Page named CustomPageRender.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Page), typeof(CustomPageRender))]
namespace FormsApp2.iOS
{
class CustomPageRender :PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        if (this.NavigationController != null)
        {
            CGRect rect = View.Frame;
            rect.Y = -44;
            View.Frame = rect;

            CGRect NavRect = NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame;
            NavRect.Y = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - 44;
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame = NavRect;
        }
    }
}
}
```